# mockmvc standalonesetup how to inject freemarker viewresolver?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm using the spring test framework present in spring 3.2.0 to test my spring mvc controllers.

Im trying to create a standalone test setup so I have total control of all variables.
I've got the test working with an InternalResourceViewResolver.
But now i'm trying to use freemarker as my templating engine and I can not figure out how to include the freemarker configuration as a bean to the standalone setup.

The following class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StandAloneRegistrationControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private UserRegistrationService userRegistrationServiceMock;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new RegistrationController())
            .setViewResolvers(viewResolver())
            .build();
}

private ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();

    freeMarkerViewResolver.setCache(false);
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setPrefix("/view/");
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setRequestContextAttribute("rc");
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setExposeSessionAttributes(true);
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setAllowSessionOverride(true);


    return freeMarkerViewResolver;
}

@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/");
    configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    Properties settings = new Properties();
    settings.put("auto_import", "/view/layouts/layouts.ftl as layout,spring.ftl as spring");
    configurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);

    return configurer;
}

@Test
public void showAddTodoForm_ShouldCreateFormObjectAndRenderAddTodoForm() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/register"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}

}
```

Gives the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Must define a single FreeMarkerConfig bean in this web application context (may be inherited): 
FreeMarkerConfigurer is the usual implementation. This bean may be given any name.; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfig] is defined
```

How can I add the freemarker configuration bean to the context so that I can inject the freemarker view resolver into the mockmvc standalone setup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MockMVC but did you try using the FreeMarker `Configuration` instead of `setFreemarkerSettings`?

Example:

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer(WebApplicationContext applicationContext) throws IOException, TemplateException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();

    freemarker.template.Configuration configuration = configurer.createConfiguration();
    configuration.addAutoInclude("/templates/include-common.ftl");
    configuration.setWhitespaceStripping(true);

    configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    configuration.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
    configuration.setURLEscapingCharset("UTF-8");
    configuration.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(applicationContext.getServletContext(), "/WEB-INF/ftl/");

    configurer.setConfiguration(configuration);

    return configurer;
}
```